# How to handle 2 submit buttons using same controller in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have 2 views that populate the same controller : `Index.aspx`and `Gestion.ascx`

Each view has a submit button which execute a method in the controller :

- Button `Enregistrer` (Index) ==> Save()
- Button `Valider` (Gestion) ==> Valider()

When I start the project I create only the button `Enregistrer` and the `Save()`methode. That's was perfectly works ! ( save some values in a list).

But when I add the button `Valider` and the `Valider()`methode, nothing works, the 2 buttons became static (dead).

So I put a breakpoint in each method, and I execute.

I find that when I click on `Enregistrer`

Comment: So I am confused, are you trying to load multiple buttons on the same HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

If you post your HTML I think you have a much better chance of getting an answer, I can't see why your form wouldn't at least submit

Comment: I already put it,,but someone edit my post